# What's the maximum number for Azure OpenAI fine-tuned model?

Tags: azure, azure-openai

According to the "quotas and lilmits", it says 2,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/quotas-limits#quotas-and-limits-reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUr8N.png)
But the FAQ says is 100
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/faq#what-is-the-maximum-number-of-fine-tuned-models-i-can-create-
So it's 2 or 100?

confirmation for the number of Azure OpenAI fine-tuned model, what's the correct number.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct limit of Azure OpenAI fine-tuned models as of now is **2**.

The [quotas and limits documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/quotas-limits) is the most up-to-date source of information on the limits of the Azure OpenAI service and it supersedes the FAQ you linked which is mostly likely to be outdated in terms of quota and limits details.